# Latch jk synchronous

Tags: latch

[image]

Is the latch in this image a synchronous J-K latch, and is the truth table correct?
Can a latch be considered a memory element that stores a state ? 
Are these answers good or not? If it is not a pic of J-K synchronous latch then how a J-K synchronous latch look?

Comment: i put a photo in the link

Comment: it is better now?:))

Comment: Yes. But the text is still not very well formulated, I must say.

Comment: pls respond.i want to know if that table correspond to latch jk synchronous and if that is a latch jk synchronous and if a latch is a memory element.

Comment: Yeah, but I haven't used a JK flip flop since I was 16 and I don't remember how it works. So I can't answer, because I'd have to spend an entire minute on google to check this.

Comment: i dont care how it works.i am interested if it is what i asked.

Comment: i cant understand you.why you came here if you dont want to help? You dont help and then you want to close this in order that others will not help me?

Comment: I came here to explain you how to write a better question, so you can eventually have answers. Now, myself, I don't actually *know* if it's the truth table of a JK, I don't remember how a JK works. And I don't want to check myself because at that point, it occurred to me that you could actually have done it yourself, it is just a simple google search. Do it.

Comment: i did. from there i get the photo. i didnt find a site in which to say this clearly. i only get this from photos from google. and among all photos i get this. and i am not sure if it is correct

Comment: if i didnt search on google how on earth i get the photo. what logic is this? i put a link.how to make more clear than that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The image shows a J-K Flip-Flop, not a latch.

The truth table is correct for a J-K Flip-Flop or Latch.

A Latch is a memory element, yes. A Flip-Flop is not.

Comment: and then how a j-k latch looks like?

Comment: why not check [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop) question.

Comment: i know s-r latch. i want j-k. are both the same? i know the difference between the two but i didnt see in my life a schematic of j-k latch synchronous.

Comment: You've already chosen an answer, so I assume your question has been answered.

Comment: i didnt.look closely.

Comment: You should have.

Comment: if you give me a schematic i choose now an answer:))

Comment: I think the confusion is in the topic "Latch jk synchronous", because a Latch isn't clocked. The truth table is the same, but the Flip-Flop is clocked (synchronous) and the Latch is not.

Comment: this was a question in an exam. and i want to know how to do because i cant ask the teacher because it is nasty. i want to know if i did a mistake or the teacher.

Comment: Then the question was flawed and could not be answered correctly except to point out the flaw.

Comment: in her mind there was no flaw:))) she was serious about all i asked

Comment: i know that a latch can be gated. only to work when the gate gives  an impulse.right? so why this latch cannot have a gate? when i say synchronous i refer to a gated latch

Answer (score -1):

**Is a latch is memory elements that can store a state.**

Yes, Latch can act as a memory element. in fact, latch is the simple version of flip-flop i.e, it is asynchronous, and the outputs can change as soon as the inputs do change.

**Is it synchronous sequential circuit?**

yes, this flip-flop is clocked sequential circuit as you are including clock signal for synchronisation.

And by the way, If you know a little about flip-flops, you can easily verify the correctness of above truth table.

Comment: i needed this for an exam. those were questions and my teacher didnt gave me points for it. and i came here to clarify if i am right or the teacher. thank you .

Comment: Better spend a little time on reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).