# How to simulate a d-flip flop counter/divider?

Tags: simulation, flipflop, counter

I would like to simulate a simple one-bit counter (or frequency divider) using the D-flip flop.

[image: 1-bit counter / frequency divider]

However, I don't want to use the abstracted D-flip flop above. Rather, I want to simulate this using primitive NOR/AND gates directly. I rigged up a D-flip flop based  on NOR Gates below.

The full simulation can be seen at this link: http://tinyurl.com/z6mae9c

However, I cannot connect the Q' output back into the "D" input without getting an error (endpoints circled in red below). Can anyone recommend how to fix this? Is this a limitation of the simulation framework? If so, what's a good package to simulate this on?

[image]

Comment: Button  Input is a true voltage source and so is Logic gate out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tinyurl.com/zonbe7q

It cant work as you expected, but I fixed the simulation

[Difference between latch and flip-flop?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop/269984#comment607977_269984)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony, the link was very helpful! I was able to finally construct a working frequency divider using the master/slave flip flop design: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-masterslaveff.html