# Question about T flip-flop

Tags: flipflop, latch

I am trying to implement a switch that works like the description in the picture. In my research I came across the T flip-flop, however a T flip-flop requires a clock signal. I don't have that.

Is there a latch that works like a T flip-flop? Is there any way to implement an asynchronous T flip-flop (with only one input pulse)?
In a sense, I want to use one input as a set and reset at the same time. The first change from 0 to 1 is used as a set and the change after that is used for the reset. Is there a name for such circuit?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between latch and flip-flop?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop)

Comment: pulse looks like a clock to me

Comment: Please ask the full question in the title. "Question about T flip-flop" is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Critical question:

a)  Do you need for any of the four time periods (t xxx) to be adjustable, or fixed within specified limits?

- or -

b) Is it important only that the four time periods occur in the order shown?

First, a T flipflop is the first part of what you want.  Your "pulse" input drives the clock input.

Second, you need more stuff.  To assure that the two outputs occur as shown, you will need at least one time delay network, and maybe two depending on your answer to the above question.  The leading negative edge of OFF goes through a short R-C time delay circuit that drives a buffer to produce the ON output after the "t switch on" period.

After the next pulse, the flipflop output gates off the ON signal, goes through another R-C time delay (t switch off).  The output of that delay gates off the OFF output.

Or something like that.  Need more timing details.